# Why isn't this basic C example working?

Tags: c

This is a basic example from The C Programming Language. I'm using Ubuntu, compiling with gcc, which came pre-packaged, and it doesn't give any errors or anything, but when I hit enter it should print a word count, etc.. (I can't even get the simpler character count to work though). I tried changing around some of the code, which did produce errors, and tried putting the final print statement in an `if (getchar()==EOF) {printf(...)}` sort of thing, but that did nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

#define IN 1 /* inside a word */ 
#define OUT 0 /* outside a word */ 

/* count lines, words, and characters in input */ 
main() 
{ 
int c, nl, nw, nc, state; 

state = OUT; 
nl = nw = nc = 0;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) 
 { 
  ++nc; 
  if (c == '\n') 
    ++nl; 
  if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') 
    state = OUT; 
  else if (state == OUT) { 
    state = IN; 
    ++nw; 
    } 
 } 
printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc); 
}
```

Comment: `when I hit enter it should print a word count, etc`. What does it do instead?

Comment: That program will keep reading until it gets EOF, at which point it'll dump some statistics about its input and exit.  Try running it, enter some text (followed by newlines), then enter ctrl-D.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260420/newbie-c-problem?rq=1

Comment: My gcc (4.8.2) gives a warning on exactly what the problem is. What version of gcc are you running if it doesn't tell you?

Comment: sorry. i copied that from the book originally, which had a typo in it. my compiler gave an error which i fixed. the answer regarding CTRL+D fixed it. this question could also be flagged as duplicate.

Comment: If there is a duplicate why did you post this? If you think the answers in the other question are not good enough, you can try offering a bounty to the question.

Comment: i didn't see it until now.

Comment: Note that for building stuff from K&R 2 you should use compiler flag `-std=c89`. Some changes to the language introduced in C99 may make the K&R2 programs invalid.   (If you only have K&R1 ... time to upgrade books :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EOF` in Ubuntu is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> then <kbd>enter</kbd>. In Windows, it is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> then <kbd>enter</kbd>, so after you input your string, use `EOF` to terminate while loop and you will get your answer as per your program body.

Answer (score -1):

Changed line:

```
main()
```

to:

```
int main()
```

---

And changed this:

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
}
```

To this:

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
return(0);
}
```

---

Compiled:

```
gcc -Wall -o test test.c
```

Created a file called "junk.txt" with the content:  `adddsadsd 33334343434243`

Then executed the program:

```
> ./test < junk.txt
0 2 25
```

It seems to work as advertised.